# why do I get a rendering error with compose printable weight?

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, rendering, quoted-printable

I am working on a project in **Android Compose** to make an info app where users can print part of the info to a physical printer. I used the **Printable Compose weight** to send the info to the printer, it has worked up until now but when I moved to the latest version of Android Studio **Hedgehog**, I get a rendering error with this weight. I haven't found any fix to this problem.

```
val printController = rememberPrintableController()

Printable(controller = printController) {

firstText
secondText
theredText
    }

                Icon( // print button
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_print_24),
                    contentDescription = "print card",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(35.dp)
                        .constrainAs(print) {
                            top.linkTo(parent.top, margin = 5.dp)
                            start.linkTo(back.end, margin = 40.dp)
                        }
                        .clickable { 
                            printController.print("Text")
                        }
                )
```